# Diagonalizing a matrix in C

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A question for homework asked to show that the matrix $[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}$  is diagonalizable, and find a basis $\alpha$, for $[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}$, where $T:C^{3}\to C^3$

$$[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}=\begin{bmatrix}(1+i)&0&0\\-2i&(1+i)&2i\\i&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ I figured I would show that there are 3 distinct eigenvalues, and use the corresponding eigenspaces as a basis.

Solving the characteristic polynomial by expanding along the first row: $$=(1+i)-\lambda[(1+i)-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-2i]$$$$=(1+i)-\lambda[(1+i)-\lambda(1+i)-\lambda+\lambda^2-2i]$$  After this I get stuck, I am not sure how to continue, do I expand $-\lambda(1+i)$ and substruct from $(1+i)$?

Comment: the eigenvalues are $1+i,1+i, 1.$ find the corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: @abel how would I find out though, the matrix isn't triangular so the eigenvalues aren't necessarily the main diagonal

Answer (score 1):

To get the eigenvalues you need to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial. It seems that you know this, but you're not sure how to solve the corresponding cubic equation. There are two ways around this either learn to solve cubic equations by hand or try to guess an eigenvalue and use that to factor the equation.

Just looking at your matrix for a few minutes you should be able to see that the column vector $(0,1,0)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1+i$. So you can factor the monomial $(\lambda-1-i)$ from you polnomial leaving you with a quadratic equation to solve. If you're not sure how to factor out this monomial then review polynomial long division.